# How to find swift @propertyWrapper annotation 's source code?

Tags: swift

I am wondering what @propertyWrapper do in source code , and because swift is a open source language, so I download all the code , but it seems no way to find the relate code to execute ,Is there any way to read ?

Comment: Are you looking for the part of the Swift compiler implementation (written in C++) that handles `@propertyWrapper`? Or are you just wondering what `@propertyWrapper` means in Swift?

Comment: @Sweeper In my understanding there will be a protocol or a struct about propertyWrapper(which defines there must have a wrappedValue property)? I want to find this protocol or struct 's source file

Comment: No there isn't. The `@propertyWrapper` attribute is one of those special attributes that is "hardcoded" into the compiler, like `@available`, `@resultBuilder` etc.

Comment: Thanks!  So it seems a way define wrappedValue must be provided without protocol? Any source code can be found on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a Swift type that contains the implementation of how `@propertyWrapper` works. The `@propertyWrapper` attribute is one of those special attributes that is "hardcoded" into the compiler, like `@available`, `@resultBuilder` etc.

> So it seems a way define wrappedValue must be provided without protocol? Any source code can be found on this?

You can find how the compiler enforces this in T[ypeCheckPropertyWrapper.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2ca2792b48339220a559e82210b663a916b25f27/lib/Sema/TypeCheckPropertyWrapper.cpp#L331)

```
PropertyWrapperTypeInfo
PropertyWrapperTypeInfoRequest::evaluate(
    Evaluator &eval, NominalTypeDecl *nominal) const {
  // We must have the @propertyWrapper attribute to continue.
  if (!nominal->getAttrs().hasAttribute<PropertyWrapperAttr>()) {
    return PropertyWrapperTypeInfo();
  }

  // Look for a non-static property named "wrappedValue" in the property
  // wrapper type.
  ASTContext &ctx = nominal->getASTContext();
  auto valueVar =
      findValueProperty(ctx, nominal, ctx.Id_wrappedValue,
                        /*allowMissing=*/false);
  if (!valueVar)
    return PropertyWrapperTypeInfo();
```

It uses `findValueProperty` to try to find a `wrappedValue` property. Notice that the `allowMissing` parameter is `false`. `findValueProperty` is declared on [line 36](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2ca2792b48339220a559e82210b663a916b25f27/lib/Sema/TypeCheckPropertyWrapper.cpp#L36) in the same file:

```
  switch (vars.size()) {
  case 0:
    if (!allowMissing) {
      std::string fixIt = "var wrappedValue: <#Value#>";
      auto fixitLocation = nominal->getBraces().Start;
      nominal->diagnose(diag::property_wrapper_no_value_property,
                        nominal->getDeclaredType(), name)
        .fixItInsertAfter(fixitLocation, "\n"+fixIt);
    }
```

`vars` is just a vector containing the properties named `wrappedValue` that are found. As you can see, if nothing is found and `allowMissing` is false, it generates a diagnostic.

Comment: wonderful explanation  thanks @Sweeper